Android Launcher App is unable to Launch Two Apps in Split-Screen Mode
I've created a simple launcher app to launch two applications in split-screen mode on the device. But I am encountering an issue where using the package name "com.Title" works for some apps but fails for others when attempting to launch them side by side.
When trying to launch certain applications using the package name, I receive an error toast stating "App not installed," even though these apps are installed on the device.
Could this issue be related to permissions or another simple oversight? Any advice on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
private lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences
private val preselectedApp1 = AppInfo(
    "com.title1",
    "com.title1.MainActivity"
)
private val preselectedApp2 = AppInfo(
    "com.title2",
    "com.title2.MainActivity"
)

